# How Can I Access Data From External Json File in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I want to access data from a json file in my file directory.

I have tried using `StreamReader` but it does not deserialize the data.

```
string json = r.ReadToEnd();

WorkFlowConfiguration items = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkFlowConfiguration>(json);

Debug.WriteLine(items.WorkFlowAction);
Console.WriteLine(items.WorkFlowAction);

items.WorkFlowAction.ForEach(el => Console.WriteLine(el.ToString()));
```

Comment: Can you see the file content in `string json` variable after line1 of your code snippet?

Comment: Do you get any error in this code? What error?

Comment: there is [File.ReadAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8) method

Comment: What result do you get right now, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Could you share your json file and model?

Comment: yes, i don't got any error in this code fragment.but still data of the json file not returns to the items . i think it is problem with desalinizing.

Comment: Hi @KelumSampathEdirisinghe ,you need to share your json file and model,it would be more helpful to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @rena thanks a lot for your cooperation. i got solved my problem. now it is working. problem was that accessing syntax.

Comment: @KelumSampathEdirisinghe I'm glad that you have resolved your issue.Could you mark the helpful answer or your own solution to close the thread.Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the external json file like below:

1.Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

2.Json file:

```
  {
    "status": "succeess",
    "code": 1,
    "message": "login succeeded!"
  }
```

3.The first way(Use `StreamReader`):

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\test.json"))
    {
         string json = r.ReadToEnd();
         Test item =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
    }
```

4.The second way(Use `File.ReadAllText`):

```
var jsonString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\test.json");
Test items =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access from startup class

```
"MySettings": {  
    "DbConnection": "abc",  
    "Email": "abc@domain.com",  
    "SMTPPort": "5605"  
  }  


public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{   
     var dbConnection= configuration["MySettings:DbConnection"];
}
```

or if you want in your controller, you must inject IConfiguration  in you constructor

```
public UserController(IConfiguration configuration)  
{  
   configuration = configuration["MySettings:DbConnection"]; 
}
```